# No module named objects [bokeh]

Tags: python, linux, bokeh

***Note from maintainers: This question is no longer relevant. The `bokeh.objects` module has not existed for years***

---

---

I'm trying to run this script:

```
#Code will be significantly simplified in the 0.4 release
import time
from bokeh.objects import GlyphRenderer
renderer = [r for r in curplot().renderers if isinstance(r, GlyphRenderer)][0]
ds = renderer.data_source
while True:
    df = pd.io.json.read_json(url+json_call)
    ds.data["x"] = x+N*i
    ds.data["y"] = df.rssi
    ds._dirty = True
    session().store_obj(ds)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    i+=1
```

from:
https://www.continuum.io/content/painless-streaming-plots-bokeh

but at this line:

```
from bokeh.objects import GlyphRenderer
```

I got:

```
No module named objects
```

The version I'm using is

0.11.1

On linux mint 17.1

Comment: 1. What version of Python? 2. Can you confirm bokeh is installed, using $PYTHONPATH/pip list bokeh?

Comment: with  bokeh --version got 0.11.1 I'm using python 2.7
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Note from maintainers: This answer is no longer relevant. The `bokeh.objects` module has not existed for years***

---

---

did you try installing [`bokeh`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh) before trying the examples? If not, just run:

```
pip install bokeh
```

and try your script again.

---

if it does not work, it's likely that the `bokeh` sources changed, so you might want to change the

```
from bokeh.objects import GlyphRenderer
```

into

```
from bokeh.models.renderers import GlyphRenderer
```

cf [the source code](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/models/renderers.py#L80)

---

At the first line of your example it states:

```
#Code will be significantly simplified in the 0.4 release
```

which means that the example's code was already about to be deprecated at the time of the writing of the tutorial.

So instead of copy/pasting that code, you should try to understand how it works, and recreate it using the documentation and sources:

- http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/quickstart.html#userguide-quickstart
- https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh

have fun!

Comment: using "from bokeh.models.renderers import GlyphRenderer" 
but know I get:  "name 'curplot' is not defined" seems that the code alone won't work

Comment: yup, I guess curplot() is defined else where, or is just for the sake of the example. I believe the documentation you're trying to copy from is just to show off principles and results, not really a base to build your own stuff upon.

Comment: Or if you look at the example's full source code, maybe it's part of the `*` it imports from `bokeh.plotting`. cf https://github.com/quasiben/bokeh_examples

Answer (score 2):

The `objects` module was deleted in [commit `5b5d28304c5ea209e243af5943917fe494d9ef9c`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/commit/5b5d28304c5ea209e243af5943917fe494d9ef9c) ([v0.7.1](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/commit/23fb4188090309945d5dba11dd6d4da34c744332)) after being deprecated in [`8bb4a2f1f43b39b869c508ef7aee69f7aabb46b8`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/commit/8bb4a2f1f43b39b869c508ef7aee69f7aabb46b8) ([v0.7.0](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/commit/430e793ef3796fff7ebc7de205938290abc7e893)). The deprecation message reads: "`use bokeh.models instead`". I leave finding `GlyphRenderer` in the current codebase as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

`conda update bokeh` solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding streaming (since that is is the example the OP was interested in), the current and stable streaming API is demonstrated here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/ohlc

This simple interface has been the way to efficiently stream to data soruces since `0.11.1`, and will continue to be going forward.

The basic idea is to construct a `dict` with all the columns of a data source, and just the *new* data that is to be appended:

```
# construct a source with x and y columns
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[....], y=[....]))

# sends the few new data points to the client, does not re-send all the data
source.stream(dict(x=[10, 11], y=[20, 21]))
```

Typically you'd probably call stream from some kind of periodic callback. The OHLC app linked above is a complete example.